# Nginx caching with variable param order

Tags: caching, nginx

I am generating a cache key with nginx based on the request URI and query params that checks memcache directly and then serves the page from PHP-FPM if a cache key is not found. My problem is that many URLs have query string options that come in in varying orders and thus generated two or more separate cache keys per response.

My cache setting is something like:

```
set $cache_key  "$uri?$args";
```

So URLs that come in like these with query string params in different orders end up generating multiple possible cache keys for the same type:

```
http://example.com/api/2.2/events.json?id=53&type=wedding&sort=title&limit=10
http://example.com/api/2.2/events.json?id=53&limit=10&type=wedding&sort=title
http://example.com/api/2.2/events.json?id=53&limit=10&sort=title&type=wedding
```

Ad nauseum for n! possibilities...

The end result is that memcache often fills up a lot faster than it should because I have a potential n!-1 duplicate copies of cached content simply because the query string parameters come in a different order. Is there a way I can order them alphabetically before setting the cache key to avoid this? Are there other ways to elegantly solve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

if you know which parameters are important for cache key generation then you could specify their manually. Based on your example I wrote next example:

```
set $cache_key "$uri?id=$arg_id&type=$arg_type&sort=$arg_sort&limit=$arg_limit";
```

Or you could use embedded perl and write your own function that will generate cache key, please see examples here http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration#Embedded_Perl_examples

Comment: The problem is there are many, many possible API calls each with their own set of parameters. Some of them are more global like `limit`, but most of them are API-call dependent. Thanks for the embedded Perl link - I will check that out while waiting on other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you're generating the links yourself, rather than trying to re-order them in nginx, could you use an output re-writer to ensure they're in a consistent order at page generation?

Comment: Yes I can, but this particular API is consumed by multiple mobile apps and JS widgets, some of which are 3rd party, so it is very difficult to enforce everywhere.

Comment: This sucks partially, but can you get more detailed with the variables. and set the cache key to be $uri?type=$arg[type]&sort=$arg[sort]&limit=$arg[limit] etc. etc. with all possible keys?

Comment: What happens if the particular `$arg[somekey]` does not exist in the current request? That approach will only work if nginx doesn't throw any sort of errors about non-existent query parameter keys.